# Is there a way to add text to sprite or movieclip not using TextField class?

Tags: actionscript-3

Is there a way to add text programmatically in as3 to a Sprite or a MovieClip without using the class [TextField](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/text/TextField.html)

TextField inherits from [InteractiveObject](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html) which is kind of heavy for what I want to do: just display text (i.e. I don't want to interact with the text).

Note: I'm aware that there is a property [selectable](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/text/TextField.html#selectable) to make the textfield not selectable. This is not the point.

Thank you

Comment: Quoting Donald Knuth here is tempting. I won't, though -- maybe you are doing this for educational purposes, you are just experimenting or you do have an actual performance problem. However, I thought I'd mention that in most situations (unless you are animating a lot of text, for instance, or need better metrics, etc) textfields are just fine.

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for an alternative to TextField because of performance issue (lot of textfield).

I agree, TextField are fine for 90 % of the situations I come across, but there is that 10% where using something lighter would dramatically improve performance.

Comment: Allan's second link would be worth checking then. That's the most performant way to draw text that I'm aware of.

Comment: What would the point be of rendering fonts with the drawing API? If you draw into a bitmap you might as well have just used a bitmap, and if you don't it's going to perform about the same as a regular textfield, plus you incur lots of costs for no clear reason. Just use a bitmap, or better, the `cacheAsBitmap` feature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways that come to mind. The first being this whereby a string is written to bitmap data: [How to draw a string on BitmapData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3435543/how-to-draw-a-string-on-bitmapdata)

Second, you could try this fast font rendering library (although I have not tried it myself) [lab.polygonal.de/2009/12/15/font-rendering-with-the-fp10-drawing-api/](http://lab.polygonal.de/2009/12/15/font-rendering-with-the-fp10-drawing-api/)

Both these solutions seem to bypass the need for creating a textfield (except the first where it gets used to create but then is discarded).

Comment: +1 for the second link. Just a note. If anyone wants to use the first option and plans to call this method repeatedly, it'd be a good idea to set the `TextField` intance as a parameter. That way you could reduce the number of instances created and control font type, color and other properties from the calling code. I'm not sure this method is going to give a significant performance gain, though (just wrote it to show how you could draw text to a Bitmap). Since the OP seems to be looking for performance, the second option, although more involved, should be more appropriate, I think.

Comment: I agree that using a bitmap is the best solution, but I'd further note that there is usually no need to actually draw into your own bitmap. Just create your textfield and set the `cacheAsBitmap` flag, and you get nearly all the benefits of a bitmap with none of the inconveniences.